# How to update Blazor (hosted) upon socket receive event

Tags: multithreading, websocket, blazor

Hello i have a blazor page in which i want to display a variable.
This variable gets updated from another thread (Task- which receives data over a websocket) and i want to display it  in a thread-safe manner:

**Blazor Page**

```
@page "/new"
@inherits NewBase
<button onclick="@(async()=>await OnRunPressed())" class="control-button">Run</button>
NewValue :@socketString

public class NewBase:BlazorComponent
    {
        [Inject] protected BenchService service { get; set; }

        protected CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
        protected string socketString;

        protected async Task OnRunPressed()
        {
            Task updateTask= Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var buffer =new byte[1024];
                ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:8500/monitor"), CancellationToken.None);
                while (true)
                {

                    await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                    this.socketString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                    this.StateHasChanged();
                }

            },src.Token);
            await this.service.HitServerAsync(); //does some stuff while the above task works
            src.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

**Update**
Thanks to @Dani now i finally at least get an error :

```
blazor.server.js:16 POST http://localhost:8500/_blazor/negotiate 500 (Internal Server Error)
Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Good question...it somehow just works.I have another `.net core` project in my solution and maybe i suppose that's why it doesn't complain.

Comment: No it works in hosted too,but that's beyond the question.

Comment: If you use `hosted` and you add  a `Console.Writeline` inside the loop you will see that you won't get anything printed to the console.And the value won't change either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are no problem about to call `StateHasChanged();` after receive data via websocket. All should to run. I have tested it (as server side) and it runs without issues:

https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/blazorTestingWebSocketsServerSide/tree/master

[image]

Also, I have tested it as client side wasm, and they are several issues:

1. You are using `ArrayPool` that is a non netstandard2.0 class.
2. WebSocket is not able to connect from wasm.

Comment: Thanks for responding , but there is a slight difference. While you are placing your main loop in the main thread,  i have it in a separate `Task`. You can see i am using `Task.Run(  {main loop } )`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, moved to a task and still running.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, I update github source code. Now you don't need to start python ws. Just download and run dotnet. Let me know.

Comment: I have edited my code accordingly and now i get an error

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian. You have >1k points. You know how this works. New issue -> new question.

Comment: @Issac, ha ha ha. I believe it :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be lacking `StateHasChanged();` at the end of the `OnRunPressed` method

I guess this is a server-side Blazor, right ?

If not, then you should know that Mono on WASM is currently single-threaded...

Comment: I have a `config` with `server-side` that i use when debugging but i use the hosted actually.In both cases (server-side and hosted) with the debugger  i get the desired value from the socket , but it does not show up in the browser.